# Detecting device rotation values

Tags: android, sensors

I looked everywhere for a solution on how to detect, and get values of how much a device moves on a table, in a flat mode.
I saw many tutorials, and they all where talking about the same methods:

```
  @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


       float[] g = new float[3];
        g = event.values.clone();

      double norm_Of_g = Math.sqrt(g[0] * g[0] + g[1] * g[1] + g[2] * g[2]);

        Normalize the accelerometer vector
        g[0] = (float) (g[0] / norm_Of_g);
        g[1] = (float) (g[1] / norm_Of_g);
       g[2] = (float) (g[2] / norm_Of_g);
        int inclination = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(g[2])));
        int rotation = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(g[0],              g[1])));
       if (rotation < 25 || rotation > 100)
```

I also saw the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html), but didn't find a solution.
to make myself more clear, I added two pictures to show which kind of movement I want to detect (although I am not the best designer (  :   )
[image]
[image]

Comment: You probably want to have a closer look at the documentation, especially http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html here : Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR In your case you're looking for the rotation around the `z` axis